# Rewrite Condition with if-not Condition

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried now many variations but got no usable result.

First issue: If someone requests http://sub.domain.de this have to be rewrite to https://[...].

Second issue: If in the requested uri is /seafdav than there should be no rewrite.

Here my different variations:

```
Redirect permanent / https://sub.domain.de/
Redirect permanent /seafdav http://sub.domain.de/seafdav/

RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301] [OR]
RewriteRule ^seafdav/$ /seafdav/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub.domain.de [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/seafdav.$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://sub.domain.de/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub.domain.de [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/seafdav.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://sub.domain.de/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Found now THE solution! :)

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ /seafdav/">
    Redirect permanent / https://sub.domain.de/
</If>
```

Comment: Kindly do share your tried htaccess Rules file in your question and let us know then, thank you.

Comment: Here you are :)